# Type inference in typescript does not work

Tags: angular, typescript

when I define in an Angular component the property `name: 'blabla';` and want to use the property binding `{{name}}`, it does not get printed. Unless I define the type myself such as `name: string = 'blabla';`

I am using the latest version of typescript. How come that the type inference is not working? Any idea? Should I change something in `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help you better, please post your code.

Comment: export class AppComponent {
  name: 'blabla';}
and then in the .component.html {{name}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not type inference that's not working. When you write some property as

```
name: 'blabla';
```

this is property declaration (note the `;` at the end). It declares property `name` with type `blabla` (TypeScript has string literal types), but it does not assign any value to it.

When you write it as

```
name: string = 'blabla';
```

you declare property `name` with type `string` and assign value `'blabla'` to it. Everything is fine.

If you want TypeScript to infer the type for `name`, try

```
name = 'blabla';
```

Comment: Thanks! I completely overlooked that.